# How to find the type of an img file so it can be mounted

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, mount

I have a .img file and I want to see what's inside of it. I tried mounting it, but I don't know what filesystem type it is. Is there a way to detect what it is so I can mount it? I'm using Ubuntu.

Essentially the command I think I need to do to browse it is:

```
mount -t <FS TYPE HERE> myimage.img /path/to/mount/dir/
```

Comment: Try `file`, what's the output? Also, there's `-t auto` in mount, which will (try to) autodetect it. And you need `-o loop` to mount an image which is not a real device.

Comment: Not sure if it works with files, but try blkid -o value -s TYPE <file>

Comment: @njsg file gives `image.img: data`. Using `-t auto` still ask me for a fs type. Thanks for the `-o loop` tip.

@AlexandreAlves The output of that command is blank.

Comment: Where did this image file come from? Can you share the first three or so lines of `hexdump -C image.img` to see if there is any clue?

Comment: @njsg afaik the `-o loop` isn't needed any more with the current mount on linux.

Comment: How big is that file anyway?

Comment: @ott-- only about 6 MB.
@njsg There are a couple actually, and they all relate to Android. For example, the system.img, userdata.img, and ramdisk.img files I built from AOSP. There's also some recovery.img files I found online, like ClockworkMod recovery images. I recently discovered the system and userdata images where `yaffs2`, and that mount couldn't mount them (at least I don't think it can), and I extracted them with `unyaffs`. Even if I found out what filesystem format the other image files where, I'd still like to know how to determine it myself if possible, for future use.

Comment: Turns out the `file` command shows `VMS Alpha executable` for the `yaffs2` file systems and shows data for recovery and boot images because it's a custom android file system. I guess the answer then is to use `file`? I'll leave this question open for a bit more, but I think @njsg should answer with that since he first suggested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mount` itself has an autodetection option, `-t auto`, you can always try that.

To check the type of some file, I usually find `file` to be a pretty good tool, perhaps `file -k` if you want to be sure it does not stop at the first match.

If `file` fails to give you any useful information, you will have to look at the file yourself and try to find some clue (say, for example, by looking at `hexdump -C`). Some file types will have the file type name or some type-specific code at the beginning. That's what `file` relies on to detect many of the filetypes.